# How to specify schema attributes for mongoose subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm building a plugin and need to specify attributes for one of the subdocument collection fields.  Someone mentioned that `statics` are **the** official way of doing this.

So, instead of...

```
var familySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    surName   : { type: String },
    members   : { type: [ personSchema ], minLength: 1, maxLength: 10 } 
});
```

... it would be this ...

```
var familySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    surName   : { type: String },
    members   : [ personSchema ]
});
familySchema.static('minLength', 1);
familySchema.static('maxLength', 10);
```

**I realize there is no `minLength` or `maxLength`.  The plugin would handle this.**

I've been looking through the docs and can't find anything that mentions the **official** way.  Is there a benefit of one versus the other?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no such thing as minLength for ref array. You have to use custom validation

```
var validateFamilyLength = function (members) {
    return members.length > 1 && members.length < 10;
};

var familySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    surName   : { type: String },
    members   : { 
        type: [personSchema], 
        validate: [validateFamilyLength, 'Not valid members count']
    } 
});
```

But i strongly recommend to use refs instead

```
var familySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    surName   : { type: String },
    members   : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Person',
        validate: [validateFamilyLength, 'Not valid members count']
    }]
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I reworded the question for clarity.  I'm trying to determine the _preferred_ way of declaring those attributes.